# Typescript Class Variable Not Updating / Retaining Value

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I am trying to create a class that will fetch / cache users from my Firestore database. For some reason, I can't seem to save or expose the previous promise that was created. Here is my class:

```
export class UserCache {
  private cacheTimeMilliseconds: number = 600000;
  private userCache: any = {};

  public getCacheUser(userid: string): Promise<User> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let d = new Date();
      d.setTime(d.getTime() - this.cacheTimeMilliseconds);
      if (this.userCache[userid] && this.userCache[userid].complete && this.userCache[userid].lastAccess > d.getTime()) {
        console.log("User cached");
        resolve(this.userCache[userid].user);
      }

      console.log("Need to cache user");
      this.userCache[userid] = {
        complete: false
      };
      this.getSetUserFetchPromise(userid).then((data) => {
        let user: User = <User>{ id: data.id, ...data.data() };
        this.userCache[userid].user = user;
        this.userCache[userid].complete = true;
        this.userCache[userid].lastAccess = Date.now();
        resolve(user);
      });
    });
  }

  private getSetUserFetchPromise(userid: string): Promise<any> {
    console.log(this.userCache[userid]);
    if (this.userCache[userid] && this.userCache[userid].promise) {
      return this.userCache[userid].promise;
    } else {
      console.log("Creating new user fetch request.");
      this.userCache[userid].promise = firestore().collection('users').doc(userid).get();
      console.log(this.userCache[userid]);
      return this.userCache[userid].promise;
    }
  }
}
```

Logs: (there are only 2 unique users, so should only be creating 2 new requests)

[image]

In the logs I can see that the promise is getting set in `getSetUserFetchPromise`, but the next time the function is called, the property is no longer set. I suspect it is either a scope or concurrency issue, but I can't seem to get around it.

I am calling `getCacheUser` in a consuming class with `let oCache = new UserCache()` and `oCache.getCacheUser('USERID')`

**Edit following Tuan's answer below**

**UserCacheProvider.ts**

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import { User } from '../static/models';

class UserCache {
  private cacheTimeMilliseconds: number = 600000;
  private userCache: any = {};

  public getCacheUser(userid: string): Promise<User> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let d = new Date();
      d.setTime(d.getTime() - this.cacheTimeMilliseconds);
      if (this.userCache[userid] && this.userCache[userid].complete && this.userCache[userid].lastAccess > d.getTime()) {
        console.log("User cached");
        resolve(this.userCache[userid].user);
      }

      console.log("Need to cache user");
      this.userCache[userid] = {
        complete: false
      };
      this.getSetUserFetchPromise(userid).then((data) => {
        let user: User = <User>{ id: data.id, ...data.data() };
        this.userCache[userid].user = user;
        this.userCache[userid].complete = true;
        this.userCache[userid].lastAccess = Date.now();
        resolve(user);
      });
    });
  }

  private getSetUserFetchPromise(userid: string): Promise<any> {
    console.log(this.userCache[userid]);
    if (this.userCache[userid] && this.userCache[userid].promise) {
      return this.userCache[userid].promise;
    } else {
      console.log("Creating new user fetch request.");
      this.userCache[userid].promise = firestore().collection('users').doc(userid).get();
      console.log(this.userCache[userid]);
      return this.userCache[userid].promise;
    }
  }
}

const userCache = new UserCache();
export default userCache;
```

**ChatProvider.ts (usage)**

```
let promises = [];

          docs.forEach(doc => {
            let message: Message = <Message>{ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() };

            promises.push(UserCacheProvider.getCacheUser(message.senderid).then((oUser) => {
              let conv: GCMessage = {
                _id: message.id,
                text: message.messagecontent,
                createdAt: new Date(message.messagedate),
                user: <GCUser>{ _id: oUser.id, avatar: oUser.thumbnail, name: oUser.displayname }
              }

              if (message.type && message.type == 'info') {
                conv.system = true;
              }

              if (message.messageattachment && message.messageattachment != '') {
                conv.image = message.messageattachment;
              }

              return conv;
            }));
          });

          Promise.all(promises).then((values) => {
            resolve(values);
          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the calling code, it could be that `getCacheUser` is called twice before firestore resolves.

As an aside, I think refactoring the class may make debugging easier. I wonder why it caches the user, promise completion status, and the promise itself. Why not just cache the promise, something like:

```
interface UserCacheRecord {
    promise: Promise<User>
    lastAccess: number
}

export class UserCache {
    private cacheTimeMilliseconds: number = 600000;
    private userCache: { [userid: string]: UserCacheRecord } = {};

    public async getCacheUser(userid: string): Promise<User> {
        let d = new Date();
        const cacheExpireTime = d.getTime() - this.cacheTimeMilliseconds

        if (this.userCache[userid] && this.userCache[userid].lastAccess > cacheExpireTime) {
            console.log("User cached");
            return this.userCache[userid].promise
        }

        console.log("Need to cache user");

        this.userCache[userid] = {
            promise: this.getUser(userid),
            lastAccess: Date.now()
        }

        return this.userCache[userid].promise
    }

    private async getUser(userid: string): Promise<User> {
        const data = firestore().collection('users').doc(userid).get();
        return <User>{ id: data.id, ...data.data() };
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, was a quick first pass for proof of concept. I will try your code suggestions and report back tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you create new `UserCache` everytime you access cache users. You have to export the instance of `UserCache` class, so just single instance is used for your app.

UserCache.ts

```
class UserCache {
}

const userCache = new UserCache();
export default userCache;
```

SomeFile.ts

```
import UserCache from './UserCache';

UserCache.getCacheUser('USERID')
```

### Update

Added some tests

```
class UserCache {
  userCache = {};

  getUser(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (this.userCache[id]) {
        resolve({
          ...this.userCache[id],
          isCache: true,
        });
      }
      this.requestUser(id).then(data => {
        resolve(data);
        this.userCache[id] = data;
      });
    });
  }

  requestUser(id) {
    return Promise.resolve({
      id,
    });
  }
}

const userCache = new UserCache();
export default userCache;
```

userCache.test.ts

```
import UserCache from '../test';

describe('Test user cache', () => {
  test('User cached successfully', async () => {
    const user1: any = await UserCache.getUser('test1');
    expect(user1.isCache).toBeUndefined();
    const user2: any = await UserCache.getUser('test1');
    expect(user2.isCache).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Still seeing the same result. Which I expected since I was already only instantiating the class once before too.

Comment: @Tristan please make sure you are not calling `new UserCache()` somewhere. I added a small test and it works properly

Comment: I edited my question above with the entire usage of the class..

Comment: In `ChatProvider`, you are using `Promise.all()` to run async code of `getCacheUser`. so it may be in race condition. The first fetch user not return the result, the second try to get and call fetch user again.